# I want regular expression (theory of automata)

Tags: regex, automata-theory

Consider the alphabet V={0, 1, …, 9} and the language L, which consists of all strings of
V, which represent all integers that are greater than 798 (for example, the strings 799, 890,
2345, 777777 belong to the language L, whereas the strings 1, 42, 711, 798 do not). Provide
a regular expression that generates all strings of the language L

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! This isn't a code writing service. Instead, describe your problem with any code you've written that you want help with. Take a minute to read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53159860/edit) your question. Since your question also sounds like it's a homework question, consider reading [How do I ask homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/10400050). It's generally not a good idea to ask for help with a homework without showing any attempt.

Comment: Please at least show an attempt at solving the problem your self before asking on SO.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Going completely classic regular expression (i.e. disjunction, concatenation, and kleene star):

```
(799|(8|9)(0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9)(0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9)(0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9)*|(1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9)(0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9)(0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9)(0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9)(0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9)*)
```

If you allow typical regex shorthands (but stay within the theoretical limits, i.e. a regular language), that can be reduced to:

```
799|[89]\d{2,}|[1-9]\d{3,}
```

You match either the number 799, a three digit number starting with 8 or 9, or a four- (or more) -digit number starting with any digit but a 0 (to disallow `0023` matching).